# Fundamental package texlive.infra not present

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

I am attempting to install TeX Live 2011 on a Windows Vista machine. The steps I followed were:

1. Downloaded `install-tl.zip` from http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html.
2. Double clicked on the directory to unzip it.
3. Launched `install-tl` from the unzipped directory.

Now, I am attempting to update the packages to the current release by
launching `TeX Live Manager 2011`. I select the following from the `tlmgr` pull-down menu:

```
Load default net repository:http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

The clicking on `Update all installed` button I get:

> Fundamental package texlive.infra not present, uh oh, goodbye

Surprisingly there is no mention of `texlive.infra` on this site.

The output of `tlmgr show texlive.infra` is below:
[image]

Similar error with `tlmgr update --self --all`:
[image]

Werner's suggestion to use `tlmgr install bin-texlive texlive.infra` seemed promising but yields the same message:
[image]

Any suggestions as to what to do to resolve this?

Comment: What does `tlmgr show texlive.infra` answer?

Comment: @egreg: Updated question to include requested output.

Comment: It's quite surprising. But probably the best place where you can get help is the [TeX Live mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live)

Comment: Do you receive the same message if you perform a command-line `tlmgr update --self --all`?

Comment: @Werner: Similar, but different message (updated question to show this).

Comment: Going just by some [Google searches](http://www.google.ca/search?q=texlive.infra+serious+error) among [TL list archives](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/19475): Try `tlmgr install bin-texlive texlive.infra`...

Comment: @Werner: That seemed like a good idea, but still yields same problem (added it to question)

Comment: I would reinstall the whole TeX Live installation, or Windows.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I am in the process of doing exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reinstalling it seems to have fixed the problem. Upon initiating the reinstall I got the following which seems to indicate that the previous install did not complete:

[image]

After the re-install, here is the output of `tlmgr show texlive.infra`:
[image]