# texlive manager fails to update packages

Tags: errors, texlive, updating

My TeXLive installation is corrupt (`mdframed` supposed to be installed, but it is not).

Running update with the `tlmgr`, fails with

```
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in C:/texlive/2011/texmf-var
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex ...

fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-format --byengine pdftex failed (status 23), output:
fatal: memory exhausted (xmalloc of 1840000008 bytes).
Running: "C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32\pdftex" --ini --jobname=amstex --progname=amstex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *amstex.ini <nul

The file amstex.fmt was not created due to some errors.
See the log file C:/texlive/2011/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/amstex.log for details.
```

I have no idea what to do. Deleted TeXLive from disk and reinstall?

EDIT: 
I reinstalled texlive, but mdframed.sty ist still missing.

Comment: The simple suggestion here is: "Yes." I don't even think you have to delete the original TeX Live. You could just overwrite it with the existing one if it is the same version. If not, then I would suggest deleting it. Why? Because there may be duplicate filenames in different locations.

Comment: I recently had an issue with [tlmgr failing to update](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/fundamental-package-texlive-infra-not-present) and I had to reinstall, so I guess it is not that uncommon.  Perhaps try `tlmgr update --self --all` first and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I checked that `mdframed.sty` has been removed from TL svn, probably by mistake.  Please report that to the TL mailing list.

Comment: @Tomek: I had a discussion with R. Kotucha about that topic and he told me that a new package of mdframed is already on ctan and soon again in TL. The error probably came from mdframed itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would start with installation check:

```
tlmgr check all
```

You can additionally check for cues the `amstex.log` file that was mentioned in the error message.

Once you know which packages are broken, you can reinstall only the affected parts with:

```
tlmgr install --reinstall package1 package2 ...
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to spend time investigating, you can reinstall everything from scratch, but then you learn nothing.